# could not load library "libstdc++.so.6" при System.loadLibrary в Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, jni

Когда я пытаюсь сделать `System.loadLibrary("MyLib");` в андроид в статик блоке происходит следующее:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1640): could not load library "libstdc++.so.6" needed by "libMyLib.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:750): library "libstdc++.so.6" not found
```

Я не в курсе, зачем ему stdc++, и даже что это. Такого в зависимостях моей библиотеки вроде как нет:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>//-D_TS_ERRNO use for Solaris C++ compiler

#include <sys/select.h>//since 2.5.0

#ifdef __linux__
    #include <linux/serial.h>
#endif
#ifdef __SunOS
    #include <sys/filio.h>//Needed for FIONREAD in Solaris
    #include <string.h>//Needed for select() function
#endif
#ifdef __APPLE__
    #include <serial/ioss.h>//Needed for IOSSIOSPEED in Mac OS X (Non standard baudrate)
#endif

#include <jni.h>
```

Я погуглил. В линуске такое решается просто строкой:

> sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6

Но в андроиде я не могу так сделать. При этом в линуксе и винде мои библиотеки подключаются и работают без проблем.
Может быть андроид хочет, чтобы я скомпилировал библиотеки для андроид отдельно, с помощью NDK? Тогда как людям удаётся использовать даже чужие библиотеки без исходников?

Answer (score 0):

Английский динамик с помощью Google Translate. Извините, если это неясно!

Вы должны использовать NDK для создания Android библиотеки. Библиотеки, установленные на типичной системе Linux очень сильно отличаются от тех, на Android.

Люди могут использовать сторонние библиотеки без источника, потому что эти библиотеки были также построены с NDK.